# dataTable = jso.getPortfolio()

Tags: ms-access, vba, adobe

I inherited an Access database and I am not a programmer at all. The person who created the database left and now when I try to open the database I get the run-time error 438: `Object doesn't support this property or method`. When I click on "debug", it highlights the line bolded below "dataTable = jso.getPortfolio()":

```
fileName = myfile.name
newFileName = Replace(fileName, ".pdf", ".txt")
fileStump = Replace(fileName, ".pdf", "")
fileStump = Replace(fileStump, "_responses", "")
'end path functions
Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(CurrentProject.Path & "\" & newFileName)
Set gApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set gPDDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    If gPDDoc.Open(myfile.Path) Then
       Dim dataTable As String
       Set jso = gPDDoc.GetJSObject
       **dataTable = jso.getPortfolio()**
    Else
```

The Access database used to work fine before. Once it was moved to a different location that is when the problems started. Any ideas on how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're missing a reference...

1. Open the database
2. Open the VBA editor window [ALT-F11]
3. Go to Tools, References menu
4. Look for a missing adobe reference and check the checkbox.

It might say 'missing' [or something like that] next to the AcroExch.PDDoc reference at the top of the list of references, or you might have to scroll down to find it alphabetically in the list of available references.

It may not be called exactly "AcroExch.PDDoc" ... so if you don't see it right away, look for 'Adobe ... ' or 'Acrobat... ' references, single click them, and look toward the bottom of the window and it may show you the 'AcroExch.PDDoc'

If none of this is resolving your problem -and since the database was moved to a different location - you might need to install the Adobe product on the new workstation before the reference is available. If so, install the Adobe product and start over at step #1.